# My domain reads site can't be reached after hosting on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting, amazon-route53

I have checked my name servers and record values in my hosted zone. They seem to be in order. I am hosting a static website using an S3 bucket. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you can access the website using the S3 buckets domain name provided by aws ([http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket_name]/](http://s3.amazonaws.com/%5Bbucket_name%5D/) or http://[bucket_name].s3.amazonaws.com/) you may have not set the correct S3 permissions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-configure-bucket-permissions